# Ha Long Bay Viewpoints

Tags: vietnam, halong-bay, viewpoint

Plenty of images show Ha Long Bay from what seems to be a somewhat elevated viewpoint. Look at the top 3 rows images from [here](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1558&bih=1961&q=ha%20long%20bay&oq=ha%20lo&gs_l=img.1.0.0l7j0i10k1j0l2.2124.5008.0.6989.8.7.1.0.0.0.234.958.0j6j1.7.0....0...1ac.1.64.img..0.8.961...0i30k1j0i5i30k1.oZRQoMmrYGM) for example.

**Where are high viewpoints from which to appreciate Ha Long Bay from?** What are the names of these viewpoints and how can one reach them?

Comment: [**Top 5 Viewpoints In Halong Bay**](https://localvietnam.com/blog/top-5-viewpoints-in-halong-bay/)

Comment: @MattAllegro - Check the date of the question. The articles was published 3+ years later and I've already been by now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the images, shown in your Google search results, were shot from the pagoda on top of Titov Hill (row 1 #3, row 4 #4, row 5 #3). Others may also be from that vantage point shot through telephoto lens.

There are other islands in Ha Long Bay with trails to vantage points, temples, caves, etc.  Most Ha Long Bay overnight trips will visit at least one such island with a high vantage point and many daytrips also do such, Titov island gets hordes of junks each day.

Comment: That appears to be it. Just read this in Lonely Planet under Essential Experiences: *Climbing to the top of Dao Titop (Titop Island) for sweeping views of magnificent Halong Bay* - There appears to be plenty of variations in the spelling, it also appears as 'Ti Top' in plenty of texts.

Comment: Like many SE Asian words, the Latin alphabet version varies from author to author, as no standardized set of rules has ever been formulated.